# Element IsDisplayed false but IsEnabled true

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, ui-automation

My automation test has broken due to changes in some controls from a normal html text input field to a kendo text numeric input field. Now i get the exception "***Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with***". What really confuses me is that Webdriver can see that these controls are enable but it also thinks the control are not displayed.. what could be the reason for this? is anyone having the issue?
My current webdriver version is 2.44.0

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Please add your Webdriver and html code.

Comment: This is due to change in the Web-Element at DOM Level, You'll have to re-check and re-locate the Web-Elements for which the exception is Thrown, Also make Sure your'e using more efficient way of Locating Web-elements like Xpath(Relative) or CSS. In-case if your'e  still getting the same Exception please add the HTML code snippet and you're implementation in your post.

Comment: Thanks for the reply i did as adviced but got the same result, i used the below

Comment: The Xpath location i use below:
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='occupancyAdultMin']"));

Comment: HTML below: <input id="occupancyAdultMin" glp-compare-le="model.occAdultMax" name="occupancyAdultMinInput" type="text" glp-pos-int="" ng-change="checkOnlyNumeric(model.occAdultMin)" ng-model="model.occAdultMin" ng-enabled="isChildOccupancy" kendo-numeric-text-box="" data-role="numerictextbox" role="spinbutton" style="display: none;" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="99" aria-valuenow="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

Definition of **ElementNotVisibleException**:

`Thrown to indicate that although an element is present on the DOM, it is not visible, and so is not able to be interacted with.`

---

As per the HTML code snippet, the **display** is **none** for the element as per the attribute: `style="display: none;"`. It means the element is present in the DOM but not visible in the webpage.

Hence, the **ElementNotVisibleException** must be coming up that results in the statement: `Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with`.